# What is the connection url of mysql database in OpenShift?

Tags: java, mysql, database, openshift

I want to connect to the MySQL database in my java application. I have database name, user name and password. But what is the `connection url` and `port number`? What is the use of environmental variables?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478390/openshift-webapps-mysql-java-connection

Answer (score 0):

Please try using below connection.

```
define('DB_HOST', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'));
define('DB_PORT',getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT')); 
define('DB_USER',getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME'));
define('DB_PASS',getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'));
define('DB_NAME',getenv('OPENSHIFT_GEAR_NAME'));

$url = 'mysql:dbname='.DB_NAME.';host='.DB_HOST.';port='.DB_PORT;
$handler = new PDO($url, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```