# Unable to connect OpenShift mysql db using java code even after creating different users in users table

Tags: java, mysql, openshift

I am trying to connect mysql which I created in "OpenShift" platform through my java code.

My connect establishment is like,

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.3.175.2:3306/sivam", "root", "root");
```

I am getting below error while running this code,

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I also did below step after googling,

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY  '***';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO  'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY  '***' WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  `root\_%` . * TO  'root'@'%';
```

but still I am getting the same error.

Also I don't know why my ip address '127.3.175.2:3306' is replaced with 'localhost' in error message. It may be duplicate question but I really searched and tried all those but nothing worked out for me.

Comment: Openshift does not accept direct connections to port 3306. It uses cartridges and API wrappers such as PHP. Otherwise, your code needs an SSH tunnel wrapper as seen in the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478390